# PHP functions not defined in command line

Tags: php

It seems quite strange that some function is defined when it is called by web browsers,
but it becomes undefined in command line mode.

For example,

```
<?php
echo function_exists('mb_detect_encoding') ? 'yes' : 'no';
?>
```

When it runs in the browsers, it prints "yes" which means this function is already defined.

But when I run this piece of code in command line, it prints "no"

Why? what settings did I miss in command line mode?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Comment: Strange? Web browser's don't normally run the command-line version of PHP: they run PHP as web server module or CGI/FastCGI.

Comment: @MikeB I am pretty sure I have installed mbstring

Comment: @Steven You wouldn't be getting undefined function if you had.

Answer (score 2):

on linux you should check /etc/php5/cli/conf.d to se if it is enabled.
Otherwise try copying from another enviroment eg /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the compile time options your distributions selects. It seems that they have enabled it in the cli interpreter but not in the apache module.

Check the [installation instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) of the mbstring extension. If you really need it you'll have to compile php for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The command `php -m` lists your active modules (*extensions*).

To see if it's active, search for `mbstring` in this list. If it isn't there, it may be:

- Only enabled in the apache_handler php.ini

or

- Disabled in the cli php.ini

Add an `extension=mbstring.so` to your global php.ini to enable it. (If it is built as shared library.)

Answer (score 0):

When calling the Script via CommandLine (CLI) be sure to use the same config File as the Webserver uses when it executes PHP.

from "php --help":

> -c | Look for php.ini file in this directory

nowadays the modules, mb_string is one of them, are loaded dynamicly...

Comment: Click "edit" to update your answer. (if that was what you wanted to do)

Comment: sorry, fairly new to stackoverflow :)